# SqlDataReader to read into List<string>

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, ado.net, sql-server-express

I am writing a method in C# to query a SQL Server Express database from a WCF service. I have to use ADO.NET to do this (then rewrite it with LINQ later on).

The method takes two strings (`fname, lname`) then returns a "Health Insurance NO" attribute from the matching record. I want to read this into a list (there are some other attribs to retrieve as well).

The current code returns an empty list. Where am I going wrong?

```
public List<string> GetPatientInfo(string fname, string lname)
{
    string connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\ADOWebApp\\ADOWebApp\\App_Data\\ADODatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

    string sqlquery = "SELECT Patient.* FROM Patient WHERE ([First Name] = '"+fname+"') AND ([Last Name] = '"+lname+"')";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    using (conn)
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader != null && reader.Read())
            {
               dt.Load(reader);
               result.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["Health Insurance NO"]));
            }
        }
     }

     return result;
}
```

Comment: Well debug it. Does it enter the `while` block? Does it actually execute the `result.Add` line? Also execute the same thing against the database yourself: take the value of `sqlquery` and run it on the database manually.

Comment: You sure you're actually getting data back?

Comment: @Arran, you're right... it's not executing that line at all. 

I did run the query manually to be sure it was correct, it returns the correct record.

Apologies, I've been inserting breakpoints in and trying to debug this for almost 3 days now...!

Comment: Knowing this now, I'm suspecting the connection string might be the culprit. I'll have a look and report back.

Comment: Yep! It was the connection string. I'm going to delete this question as it's misleading for those that might stumble upon it.

Comment: @reallybadatmath: You have the mentioned bugs anyway. So loading a `DataTable` in a loop with `Load` is pointless, using no sql-parameters is dangerous, using `SqldataReader.Read` with `DataTable.Load` is not necessary, using a `DataTable` at all when you need a list is redundant.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I did end up taking on all your suggestions with the code once I got it working. Many of the bugs came about from me trying all sorts of things to get the code working, my initial attempts did look similar to what you had provided.

EDIT: I also thought I had already marked your code as the answer. My apologies.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are trying to load a `DataTable` via `DataTable.Load` >in a loop<. You just need that once. You're also using `reader.Read()` in the loop. [`SqlDataReader.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) advances the reader to the next record without to consume it. If you're going to use `DataTable.Load` you don't need to read the reader first. So you just have to remove the loop completely  to load the table.

But since you want to return a list you don't need the `DataTable` at all, just loop the reader:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
using (conn)
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            result.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["Health Insurance NO"]));
        }
    }
}
```

Apart from that, you are open for sql-injection without sql-parameters.

Comment: +1 Because I just needed a quick simple way to do this. HOWEVER - and this does not detract from this answer - you need to watch for cast errors or DBNull values. I only have 5 columns to read, so refactored into result.Add( createNewMyObjectFromReader() ) and handled each column in there....    if (System.DBNull.value != reader["someColumn"])

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way:

```
 conn.Open();
 using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
 {
     dt.Load(reader);                  
 }

 foreach (var row in dt.AsEnumerable())
 {
     result.Add(row["Health Insurance NO"].ToString());
 }
```

Comment: You would load the table in a loop? ;-)