# How to link database with C#

Tags: c#, database

Okay, I am wanting to basically connect my windows form application in C# to my database, what I want it to do is display a random word from the database into the label of my form. When I say display a random word I mean display a random word from the 20 words in a table of my database. I was wondering how would you do this? I really dont want the answer as I want to learn, but could you explain how would I do this?

Thanks in advance:)

I am wanting to connect the database using Access rather than the framework provided by .NET

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! I recommend you take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and head back when you have a specific programming-related question.

Comment: Do some research on Linq-To-Entities (Entity Framework), Linq-To-SQL, and ADO.net. These are all available frameworks within .net that you can use with your WinForms app to access an SQL database.

Comment: Try to use `Google`before asking a question.For example I get this after a simple searching: [Beginners guide to accessing SQL Server through C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C)

Comment: @DavidKhaykin thanks but i want to link if using access rather than using the frameworks provided by .NET

Comment: @Selman22 Thanks, but my main question was how do I get a random word from the database put into the label

Comment: That is an important detail that you did not include anywhere in your question! How can anyone guess you are using Access?

Comment: Return your words into a list, generate a random number between the max and min ordinals, and pick that word out of the list by ordinal.

Comment: ^^ then, set that word to a label and you're done! Man that's a full blown solution in two comments!

Comment: @DavidKhaykin Sorry Im new to this but thanks for the heads up! I've updated the question:P

Comment: @Tim If you're not busy could you please put it as an answer and just provide a wee bit of code so I get the jist, thanks

Comment: @user3325176 My question are those 20 words in a single cell or more rows but still one column?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15128361/546000

Answer (score 3):

First of all I would like to suggest to use google first [Beginners guide to connect SQL with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) then I would like you to post question regarding to one topic for instance - Connect SQL with C#. And the part with picking random word should be another solo question.

Anyway I hope this will work for you, but please, keep in mind that we are not here to code for you without any coding effort and your code.

My code:

```
List<string> wordList = new List<string>();
string connection = "YourConnectionString";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection);
string query = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE ID=@param"; // add as many conditions as you need
OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", textBox1.Text); //example of parameter
con.Open();
OleDbDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read()) //this will loop through all rows with given conditions.
{

     wordList.Add(rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("YourSQLColumn")).Trim());

}

con.Close();
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomint = rnd.Next(1, 20); // generates a random number between 1 and 20
label1.Text = wordList[randomint].ToString();
```

Comment: Each word is in 1 column, so 20 rows and 1 column

Comment: @user3325176 try my edit. Does it work for you?

Comment: If you set the rnd.Next to the lower and upper bounds of the list, it'll be dynamic (so you don't need to recode when you add a 21st word, which I assure you, is going to happen) I believe list ordinals start at 0...

Comment: I am using OleDbConnection btw, also it doesnt recognise the 'Items'

Comment: Try wordList.Add instead

Comment: Thats worked but it just doesnt display a random word ://

Comment: @user3325176 you get any errors or exception? Try to debug on ` wordList.Add` and see what is going on there. I think your conditions for select or connection arent properly set.

Comment: Nope no errors at all dude, im confused

Comment: @user3325176 Try to debug then on the line where the items are added to `wordList`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample to get you started

```
public static void Main()
{
    string connectionString = "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=InsertDatabaseNameHere; connection timeout=30";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select ColumnName from TableName", connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));
    }
    connection.Close();

}
```

Comment: I think it is not a good way to index column as table structure might change.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a SQLDataReader and convert to a list...you just have a one-dimensional list of strings. You'll be looping through the results and adding them to a list. (There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but you've only got 20 strings, not 20,000, so I don't think you need to get crazy with this)

Here's another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299935/sqldatareader-to-read-into-liststring) to get you started...this answer is probably what you need.

You just set your Datareader up against Access (there's a bazillion hits on doing this), convert it to a list, and off you go...