# Select data from access database using class

Tags: c#, ms-access

I tried to retrieve data from access database. I wrote the function inside of a class and i got this error. So please anyone know an answer for this question please let me know how can i fix it. the below function is wrote in a class and i need to know how to display data to listview control by using this function and how to call it form load event. i tried to fix this lots of time and i still didn't get a solution for this.

```
public List<String> displayRoom()
{
    List<String> rooms = new List<String>();

    String query = "select * from room";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connect);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read()){
        rooms.Add(reader["buyer_name"].ToString());
        rooms.Add(reader["room_type"].ToString());
        rooms.Add(reader["date_from"].ToString());
        rooms.Add(reader["date_to"].ToString());
    }
    return rooms;
}
```

Comment: What was the error you got? Give us some more information!

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView" This is the error i'v got

Comment: Can you show us the statement where you assign the list-data to your listview?

Comment: @Matthijs did you mean form load event???

Comment: You must have some sort assignmentstatement assigning the data you retrieved to the ListView; My best guess on what you have is this: ListView = displayRoom();

Comment: Hi...
refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299935/sqldatareader-to-read-into-liststring
surely it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can *read data properly* from database then just in the form load or `constructor` of the form class write following line:

```
//here dbClass is an instance of your database class
List<String> rooms = dbClass.displayRoom(); //though `get/load rooms()` would be more appropriate
foreach (string s in rooms)
  {
    ListViewItem lv=new ListViewItem(s);
    listView1.Items.Add(lv); //listView1 is the ListView instance in your form
  }
```

**EDIT**

If your `Form` has name `Form`, then either in `Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` or in `public Form1()` constructor (after `InitializeComponent` is called), you can put the above code.

Comment: Can you explain above code with my full code it's a function in database class
may i insert all the data of the class file

Comment: I can use the code like above. but my function is placed on a class so i need to know how to call it into form load

Comment: If your class name which reads from database is `DatabaseClass`, in the form load method create an instance `DatabaseClass dbClass=new DatabaseClass;`, then use above code.

Answer (score -2):

The ExecuteReader requires an open connection:

```
connect.Open();
```

Insert just above

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

And close the connection when you are done

```
}
connect.Close();
return rooms;
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca.aspx) for more info...

Comment: If you are telling him about the connection, it should be closed too. Perhaps a Using statement?

Comment: But this doesn't answer his question; if you look at the error he provided in the comments. Also you can not open a command, you should open a connection, in this case "connect"

Comment: The error was not provided in the original post but added later on....